# Which design pattern is behind Entity Framework's IEntityWrapper interface?

Tags: design-patterns, entity-framework-6

I was examining EF6 code. I encountered IEntityWrapper interface, BaseEntityWrapper class and EntityWrapper.

What is the design pattern implemented here?

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/Internal/IEntityWrapper.cs
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/Internal/BaseEntityWrapper.cs
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/Internal/EntityWrapper.cs

Comment: I guess [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Basically two design patterns are implemented in Entity Framework

1. Unit Of Work pattern
2. Repository pattern

It is a generic wrapper over the Repository pattern, and the `DBContext` class represents Unit Of Work Pattern.

Repository pattern is behind the `IEntityWrapper` interface.

Comment: You mean IEntityWrapper is a generic wrapper for repository? But it actually wraps the Entity!